# Как подключить мобильник к Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, mobile-development, visual-studio-2015

Буквально вчера читал, что вышел релиз Visual Studio 2015. Рекламируется кроссплатформенная мобильная разработка на C++. Скачал, установил... Не могу поставить эмулятор, требует Windows 8 (у меня 7-ка). Решил подключить свой андроид телефон. Установил на телефоне режим разработчика, отладка USB. Но студия его не видит. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Эм, ответ ведь есть в вопросе, разве нет? Используйте Windows 8.1 или подождите ещё 8 дней и обновитесь до Win10

Comment: А если я не могу пока что перейти на 8-ку или 10-ку? На 7-ке никак?

Comment: @sitev_ru Наверное никак. Майкрософт начинает душить семерку все сильнее, скоро и за восьмерку возьмется.

Comment: Странно конечно, зачем душить 7-ку и 8-ку, если 10-ка вроде как будет бесплатной?

Comment: 10-ка будет доступна для обновления 7-ки и 8.x-ки бесплатно в течении года. Сама 10-ка не будет бесплатной. Давно пора отказываться от старых ОС. Нечего тащить их за собой.

Comment: Хотя может я и не прав. Эмулятор 100% нельзя на Win7 запустить, а вот информации по прямому подключению к устройству я не нашёл.